# Python: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list'

Tags: python, numpy, integration

I'm trying to do a trapz integration, with a function using 2 lists and 1 `numpy.ndarray`. It won't work, and I can't work out whether I need to convert my lists to some other data type. I'm happy that the actual function is correct, but I'm not sure how to proceed?

The function is:

```
BB_flux = trapz((1./lamz)*flux*T,x=lamz)/trapz((1./lamz)*T,x=lamz)
```

where `T` and `lamz` are lists and `flux` is a ndarray that I have made by interpolation.

Both `T` and `lamz` are made by reading from a csv file and then appending the values to `T` and `lamz` as floats.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear about the problem - what were you expecting the outcome of e.g. `1./lamz` to be?

Comment: Im supposed to just get a large number out as the value of BB_flux. Is there a data type that trapz prefers? because none of the other variables are floats so I'm not sure how the error is coming about

Comment: @ThomasBennett. You are attempting to divide the value `1.` by an ordinary python list, which is not supported. Were you expecting the result to be a list of floats? To achieve that you would need to use a list comprehension: `[1./x for x in lamz]`.

Comment: I agree with @ekhumoro. Alternatively, you can do `lamz = np.array(lamz)` before the given line, then you don't need to change that one. But @ekhumoro's solution is cleaner!

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn’t support arithmetic operation (/,*,+,-) on lists.
The operators + and * are list operations.

Since you use numpy, you can convert your lists to numpy arrays.

If you want to keep lamz and T as lists you can use

```
w = numpy.asarray(T)/numpy.asarray(lamz)
BB_flux = trapz(w*flux,x=lamz)/trapz(w,x=lamz)
```